# How do I tell memcached to ignore the django admin page?

Tags: django, nginx, memcached, gunicorn

I'm running memcached infront of django without any explicit configuration in my code. I.e. nothing more than

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    ...
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    )
```

and

```
CACHE_BACKEND = 'memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/'
```

in my `settings.py`. This works great, in fact so great that it's caching my admin page leaving me no way to moderate live actions on the site until the cache refetches the data. Is there a regex I can throw somewhere to let memcached know to leave my admin page alone? (I'm also using nginx and gunicorn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maybe write your own middleware class or extend from one that django provides.

Specify a dictionary of urls in your settings file:

```
CACHE_IGNORE_REGEXPS = (
)
```

Write a Middleware Class:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
import re
import settings


class MyMemCacheMiddleWare:
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        cacheIt = True
        theUrl = request.get_full_path()

        # if it's a GET then store it in the cache:
        if request.method != 'GET':
            cacheIt = False

        # loop on our CACHE_INGORE_REGEXPS and ignore
        # certain urls.
        for exp in settings.CACHE_IGNORE_REGEXPS:
            if re.match(exp,theUrl):
                cacheIt = False

        if cacheIt:
            key = '%s-%s' % (settings.CACHE_KEY_PREFIX,theUrl)
            cache.set(key,response.content)     

        return response
```

[Alex Holt](http://soyrex.com/) has a pretty neat [tutorial](http://soyrex.com/articles/django-nginx-memcached/) about django, memcached and Nginx maybe you wanna read through that to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem and I came up with an another minimal solution.

First, create your own middleware that inherits the original `UpdateCacheMiddleware`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from django.conf import settings
from django.middleware.cache import UpdateCacheMiddleware


class MyUpdateCacheMiddleware(UpdateCacheMiddleware):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        full_path = request.get_full_path()
        # loop on our CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_IGNORE to ignore certain urls
        for ignore in settings.CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_IGNORE:
            if ignore.match(full_path):
                return response
        # ignore patterns missed, pass it to the original middleware
        return super(MyUpdateCacheMiddleware, self).process_response(
            request, response
        )
```

Then create an ignore regex list in your settings similar to that:

```
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_IGNORE = (
    re.compile(r'^/admin/'),
)
```

Now all you need to do is to replace your `UpdateCacheMiddleware` with the one you created:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'myapp.lib.middlewares.MyUpdateCacheMiddleware',
    # ...
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

Cheers.